# Submodule of a finitely generated module over a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

If $R$ is a Dedekind domain then is a submodule of a finitely generated $R$-module also finitely generated over $R$?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a Dedekind ring $R$ is Noetherian, every submodule of a finitely-generated $R$-module is finitely-generated.